# Timer not working inside class that extends SurfaceView and implements Runnable

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a game and I have this class that I call GameLoop that extends SurfaceView and implements Runnable. I want to call methods inside the games sprite objects and change some their values in intervals. Therefore I came up with the idea to have a Timer object inside the constructor of the GameLoop class and call the methods via a manager for all the game sprite objects. I have done this before, and then it workt, but when I do it now the game force to close! What could be wrong and is their a better way to do this?

This is the code for the time interval I have in the constructor of the GameLoop class. When I remove the code, it works fine, but I dont get any interval!? Help is preciated! Thanks!

```
        // Set timer to call method to change directions of Circle object in interval
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run() {
            // Call method to change direction
        }

    }, 0, 1000); // 1 sec
```

Comment: Please post the appropriate stacktrace shown in LogCat...

Comment: did you that before in Android or just java?

Comment: It seems like it's working now! I use some code that I got from an answer that later get downvoted and then was erased! I don't know why it was downvoted. Perhaps not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your changes to the screen must go in the main thread or through runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /////your code here
    }
});
```

You can add a sleep(1000,0) and check the elapsed time between calls to make it fixed rate.

```
public class MyUpdater extends Thread
{

long milis;
long nanos;

private ArrayList<Updatable> updatables;

public MyUpdater(long milis,long nanos)
      {
      super();

      this.milis=milis;
      this.nanos=nanos;

      updatables=new ArrayList<Updatable>();
      }

public void run()
      {

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

       long previousTime=System.nanoTime();

       while(true)
           { 
            sleep(milis,nanos);

            long now=System.nanoTime();
            long elapsedTime=previousTime-now;

            previousTime=now;

            update(elapsedTime);

           }

         }
        });
      }


public synchronized void addUpdatable(Updatable object)
      {
      updatables.add(object);

      }

public synchronized void removeUpdatable(Updatable object)
      {
      updatables.remove(object);

      }

private synchronized void update(long elapsedTimeNanos)
      {
      for(Updatable object: updatables)
        {
         object.onUpdate(elapsedTimeNanos);
        }

      }
}
```

You need now an Interface or an base Updatable class.

```
public Interface Updatable
{
public void onUpdate(long elapsedTimeNanos);
}
```

And an example

```
public class MyJozanClass implements Updatable()
{
private float adjuster=0.00002f; ////you will have to adjust this depending on your ///times

float x=0;
float y=0;

public MyJozanClass()
{
}

public void onUpdate(long elapsedTimeNanos)
{

float newX=x+adjuster*elapsedTimeNanos;
float newY=y+adjuster*elapsedTimeNanos;

//////change positions

}

}
```

In general this solution is preety much like AndEngine system.

Comment: Bu if I add sleep then it would affect the rest of the game!?

Comment: It will only affect the objects inside thar Runnable. You can have one for each call, one for each object or what I think it´s better, one updating thread and a list of objects Updatables that are called each time

Comment: Hmm, fint it a little bit hard to understand! I guess I must leran more about Threads. I was thinking of to have some sort of timer in each object, soo the sprite objects could live their own life, but that is perhaps not a optimal way to do it!?

Comment: I guess it depends on the amount of objects you have. If you have a lot, they wont be updated, added or deleted to/from the list until all others have. Create a Thread is heavier than register an object in an array, but you make sure that thread is independent. I think the list with a single Thread as an easier solution but that´s up tou you

Comment: I'm not sure about how do you mean by this: Create a Thread is heavier than register an object in an array, but you make sure that thread is independent. Could you show some simple code? It's esaier to understand

Comment: I posted the basic code. I just made it here so there might be some error. create a MyUpdater and call to start() when you want it started. It works like a normal thread.

Comment: I may have made a little mistake with the place to put runInUri... If it doesn´t work take that lines out, make class implements Runnable instead of extending thread and use runInUri with it like in first example